# Adjust playback speed on Vimeo to watch videos faster

Tags: vimeo

Vimeo's player doesn't have any option to adjust play speed settings.  Is there some way to watch content at a faster speed?

YouTube lets you adjust video play speed by clicking the gear icon and clicking on "speed" and Windows Media Player by View -> Enhancements -> Play Speed settings.

Answer (score 8):

[Create a bookmarklet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFdz2LrkNuQ) with the following content:

```
javascript: var v = document.querySelector('video'); var t = prompt('Set the playback rate'); v.playbackRate = parseFloat(t)﻿
```

Then simply launch the bookmarklet when playing a video on Vimeo and enter your desired playback speed.

Answer (score 3):

To do this, download VLC Player, pull up the Media menu, choose Open Network Stream, and paste in the https://player.vimeo.com/video/########## URL in.  When it starts playing, go to the Playback menu and then choose "Speed".

If a video is embedded in a page, you can view the source of the page and search for player.vimeo.com to try to find the URL (or use the browser's inspector to find it if viewing source doesn't work).  If you're watching a video on the Vimeo website, click the share icon in the player and find the player.vimeo.com URL in the window that comes up.